# Java Array Order a Object List as per the variable in subclasses

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I have a parent Class "Content" two subclasses of it "Document" and "Assessment".

```
@Document(collection = "content")
public class Content {
@Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
//this type is from enum
  private Type type;

}
public enum Type {
  DOCUMENT,
  ASSESSMENT
}
public class Document extends Content {
   private String priority;
}

public class Assessment extends Content {
   private String priority;
}

public interface ContentRepository extends MongoRepository<Content, String> {
  Page<Content> findAllByTypeIn(List<Type> types, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In service Layer I get List of the Content.

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
  List<Type> typeList = Arrays.asList(Type.DOCUMENT, Type.ASSESSMENT);
  Page<Content> contents = contentRepository.findAllByTypeIn(typeList , pageable);
List<Content> contents = contents.getContent();
**//need to order this List**
```

Here I get a List of contents with type DOCUMENT or ASSESSMENT. I need to order this List as per the priority. Note: The priority is in both subclasses. I can't move this to super class as there are more subclasses of that parent class which does not have this 'priority' Variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say create another intermediate abstraction for the classes those contains `priority`. That will also be correct as per design standards. And that way you can easily sort it with that field.

Something like `PriorityContent` class that extends `Content`. And `Document` and `Assessment` will extend `PriorityContent` rather than the `Content`.

[image]